# Understanding Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

I am looking at a code example, and I am not sure what this means.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("MyProperty.properties");
```

It appears that it looking to read a property file but I am not sure where MyProperty.properties is located.

I appreciate for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It appears that it looking to read a property file but I am not sure where `MyProperty.properties` is located.

As you currently have it there, that will look for the `MyProperty.properties` file at the top of your classpath.  The could be in your `src/main/resources` directory or other src folder -- it would depend on how your application (jar/war) is built.

If you are building a jar then you should be able to unpack it and see your properties file at the top level of the jar.  If you are building a war, maybe it should be in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.  Again, it depends on how it was built.

Typically the `log4j.properties` file is also at the top of the classpath so you may want to look for that file and put your property file alongside it.